# How to set div's order by condition in Jquery /js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stack divs one after another, by class, so if div has class of "icon1" then the following div will be "icon2". I want to to id within the each loop.. to prevent multiple Dom manipulations

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "foo"
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "foo"
}];

var type = '';
var template ='';
$.each(arr, function() {

  if (this['id'] == 1) {
    type = 'icon1';
  } else {
    type = 'icon2';
  }
   template += '<div class="icon '+type+'">'+
   '<p>ID: '+type+' Name: '+this['name']+'<p></div>';

});
$('#foo').html(template);
```

```css
.icon1 {
  color: red;
}

.icon2 {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="foo">

</div>
```

The result i'm looking for will be :

```
   icon1
   icon2
   icon1
   icon2
   icon1
   icon2
   etc...
```

Comment: Is the value also going to stay the same as `icon1` or `icon2`?

Comment: If you're doing this to style the alternate rows you could just `div:nth-child(odd) { ... } div:nth-child(even) { ... }`.

Comment: You have 5 of `icon2` while there is 3 of `icon1`. It has no sense!

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens - the idea is to stack all the div's by class - one after the other.... if the previous div isn't icon1 - then display them one by one - check out my last update... thanks

Comment: What about overflowed elements?

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens i rather do it with js/ jquery.. thanks

Comment: @RoyBarOn, I mean overflow as higher amount of elements.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens Thank, i'm not sure i understand, i want to order div's by their class.. so icon2 will follow icon2... what do you mean by "overflow"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162092/discussion-between-miquel-al-vicens-and-roybaron).

Comment: @gurvinder372 since i didn't found any solution yet please re-post your answer and i'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution:

```js
var array = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "foo"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "foo"
  }
];

var lsts = [ [], [] ];
$.each( array, function() {
  lsts[ this.id - 1 ].push( this );
} );
var lst1 = lsts[ 0 ],
  lst2 = lsts[ 1 ];
for ( var i = 0, l = lst1.length, l2 = lst2.length; i < l || i < l2; i++ ) {
  if ( i < l )
    appendElement( lst1[ i ] );
  if ( i < l2 )
    appendElement( lst2[ i ] );
}

function appendElement( obj ) {
  $( '#bar' ).append( '<div class="icon' + obj.id + '">' + obj.name + '</div>' );
}
```

```css
.icon1 {
  color: red;
}

.icon2 {
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bar"><div>
```

Beware of another ID numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use css **nth-child** property to get this styles

```
div:nth-child(odd) {
  color: red;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  color: pink;
}
```